# Labels in the Digit1 dataset for semi-supervised learning

Tags: machine-learning, semi-supervised-learning

I am working with the "Digit1" dataset introduced by the book "Semi-Supervised Learning" by chapalle et. al, as one of the benchmark datasets in the field.

In the dataset description located at:
http://olivier.chapelle.cc/ssl-book/benchmarks.pdf comes:

> The class label was set according to the
>   tilt angle, with the boundary corresponding to an upright digit.

Somewhere else in the document comes that there are only 2 classes in this dataset. From these two explanations I still can not understand how exactly the labels are defined. I would be thankful If someone could help me with this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems this set contains only rotated "1"s (plus some noise and rescales), and the decision is whether the digit is rotated right or left from the upright position.